# Undervoltage icon (bolt) with ATX power supply

Tags: power-supply

I had two cellphone chargers in parallel (5.1v - 2A each one) and the Raspberry show me the yellow bolt. I know that this icon means undervoltage so I replaced the chargers with an ATX power supply that can provide 5v - 30A. I still get the yellow bolt. The raspberry works grat, never reset, turned off or had a bad performance but the icon it's annoying. Maybe it's a software bug or a bad reading of the internal voltmeter/ammeter. 
Somone heard that before?

It's a Rapsberry Pi 3B with Raspbian (lastest version) in a 32GB SD Card.

Regards,
Lucas

Comment: I get this on a RPi 2 as well - power supply is known to be more than adequate

Comment: Any your question is … Incidentally **never** connect the outputs of 2 switch mode power supplies. Have you **measured** the voltage?

Comment: I'm electronic student, so I know that to connect 2 power supplies in parallel you have to protect each output with a diode (of course, low drop voltage diode). Also, with the ATX power supply I still have the bolt so wasn't a power supply failure. I measured the voltage in the 5v pins in the Raspberry and I get 4.9v-5v. I measured with an osciloscope and a professional voltmeter so I don't think that the measure it's wrong.
Thanks!